# Template file not working correctly in CodeLite?

Tags: c++, templates, codelite

Every time I create a new project in my workplace I run into the problem with templates. For example, I'll create a new class, which CodeLite will create a .h file and a .cpp file for me, and then I'll change that .cpp file into a .template by renaming the file. It sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't. Sometimes I have to clean my workplace for it to work, other times I need to exit out of CodeLite and reopen it. This time these solutions are not working for me, but maybe I am missing something. Here's my code:

**.h file**

```
#ifndef TABLE1_H
#define TABLE1_H
#include <cstdlib>    // Provides size_t

namespace main_savitch_12A
{
    template <class RecordType>
    class table
    {
    public:
        // MEMBER CONSTANT -- See Appendix E if this fails to compile.
        static const std::size_t CAPACITY = 811;
        // CONSTRUCTOR
        table( );
        // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        void insert(const RecordType& entry);
        void remove(int key);
        // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        bool is_present(int key) const;
        void find(int key, bool& found, RecordType& result) const;
        std::size_t size( ) const { return used; }
    private:
        // MEMBER CONSTANTS -- These are used in the key field of special records.
        static const int NEVER_USED = -1;
        static const int PREVIOUSLY_USED = -2;
        // MEMBER VARIABLES
        RecordType data[CAPACITY];
        std::size_t used;
        // HELPER FUNCTIONS
        std::size_t hash(int key) const;
        std::size_t next_index(std::size_t index) const;
        void find_index(int key, bool& found, std::size_t& index) const;
        bool never_used(std::size_t index) const;
        bool is_vacant(std::size_t index) const;
    };
}
#include "table1.template" // Include the implementation.
#endif
```

**.template file**

```
template<class RecordType>
table<RecordType>::table(){
    used = 32;
}
```

**main file**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "table1.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My template and my .h files are called table1. The error I am getting when I run the program is in the template file. It reads: "table does not name a type" How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template implementation your are missing the namespace, use this:

```
template <class RecordType> 
main_savitch_12A::table<RecordType>::table()
{
    used = 32;
};
```

Comment: This works correctly, but when I try to create a table instance in the main file using `table<int> h1;` it gives me an error saying table was not declared in this scope. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Hmm, I have to address the namespace first like `main_savitch_12A::table<int> h1;` Thank you for your answer I'll give you best answer soon

Comment: Do `main_savitch_12A::table<int> h1;`